# Substitution with \s does not work as expected

Tags: regex, perl

I write regex to remove more than 1 space in a string. The code is simple:

```
my $string = 'A string has more than 1      space';
$string = s/\s+/\s/g;
```

But, the result is something bad: 'Asstringshassmoresthans1sspace'. It replaces every single space with 's' character.

There's a work around is instead of using \s for substitution, I use ' '. So the regex becomes:

```
$string = s/\s+/ /g;
```

Why doesn't the regex with \s work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\s` is only a metacharacter in a regular expression (and it matches more than just a space, for example tabs, linebreak and form feed characters), not in a replacement string. Use a simple space (as you already did) if you want to replace all whitespace by a single space:

```
$string = s/\s+/ /g;
```

If you only want to affect actual space characters, use

```
$string = s/ {2,}/ /g;
```

(no need to replace single spaces with themselves).

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is that `\s` is a character class, not a literal character. Just as `\w` represents alphanumeric characters, it cannot be used to print an alphanumeric character (except `w`, which it will print, but that's beside the point).

What I would do, if I wanted to preserve the *type* of whitespace matched, would be:

```
s/\s\K\s*//g
```

The `\K` (keep) escape sequence will keep the initial whitespace character from being removed, but all subsequent whitespace will be removed. If you do not care about preserving the type of whitespace, the solution already given by Tim is the way to go, i.e.:

```
s/\s+/ /g
```

Answer (score 1):

`\s` stands for matching any whitespace. It's equivalent to this:

```
[\ \t\r\n\f]
```

When you replace with `$string = s/\s+/\s/g;`, you are replacing one or more whitespace characters with the letter s. Here's a link for reference: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't the regex with \s work?

Your regex with `\s` does work. What doesn't work is your replacement string. And, of course, as others have pointed out, it shouldn't.

People get confused about the substitution operator (`s/.../.../`). Often I find people think of the whole operator as "a regex". But it's not, it's an operator that takes two arguments (or operands).

The first operand (between the first and second delimiters) is interpreted as a regex. The second operand (between the second and third delimiters) is interpreted as a double-quoted string (of course, the `/e` option changes that slightly).

So a substitution operation looks like this:

```
s/REGEX/REPLACEMENT STRING/
```

The regex recognises special characters like `^` and `+` and `\s`. The replacement string doesn't.

If people stopped misunderstanding how the substitution operator is made up, they might stop expecting regex features to work outside of regular expressions :-)